# import file in PyCharm for UnitTest Tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, import, pycharm

I am using PyCharm (Build #PC-201.6668.115 built on April 7, 2020) on Mac OS Catalina version 10.15.3. I'm getting "Unresolved reference 'activities'" when I try to import activities.py for unittest.  I read the thread on StackOverflow and set the folder Python3Bootcamp to "mark as Sources Root" and Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console to check "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH".

What can I do to properly import the Python file for UnitTest?

This seemed to satisfy PyCharm's error messages:

```
from testing.unittest.activities import eat, nap
```

but when I ran "python3 tests.py" I got "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testing'"

[image: trouble importing file in PyCharm]

Comment: Why do you use `/` instead of dots in the import in the screenshot?

Comment: PyCharm, although updated to latest, isn't perfect.  Just "from activities" is enough to work even though the message in the IDE says it won't work.

Comment: Do you mean `from activities import ...` in `tests.py`? It will work in some cases but not always see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51820200/2787185